# Local Localisation with particle filter

Tags: mobile-robot, localization, odometry, particle-filter

I am doing Local Localisation with sonar, particle filter (i.e all particles are initially with robot pose).

I have grip map of environment. When I execute algorithm in environment (where doors are closed/open), particles are not able to followup the robot.

I don't have random particles since I know the initial position of the robot exactly.

Adding random particle will change the pose of robot (i am find median of particles as robot pose).

Any idea/methods how to improve local localisation?

I want to know, do I need random variable if I am doing local localisation? And how do I improve localisation if there are many changes in the map without adding random particles?

Comment: Hi Nadosh and welcome to the Robotics Stack Exchange. It's unclear to me what you are asking precisely. Can you ask a more pointed question?

Comment: i want to know do i need random variable if i am doing locallocalisation.and how to improve localisation if many changes in map without adding random particles.

Comment: Hi Nadosh, welcome to *robotics*. On stack exchange, comments are there to help improve questions (and answers), so it is better to edit your question in response to a request for clarification in a comment. That way, once the question has been improved, the comments can be tidied up (deleted) and they will no longer distract people from the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

Of course adding random particles will change the pose of the robot. That's the point: To add randomness to account for errors you can't compute yourself. You should add random particles every time the state of the robot may change, then adjust the weight of the particles based on which seem likely given sensor data.

This is a very basic definition of particle filters. I suggest you roll up your sleeves and do some more research on the subject.